# Resize an image to aspect ratio 16:9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to resize the uploaded image to `16:9`. I've been trying all day and this is the best I've done so far.

```js
const resizeResult = await manipulateAsync(
  uploadResult.uri,
  [
    {
      resize:
        uploadResult.width > uploadResult.height
          ? { height: 900 }
          : { width: 1600 },
    },
    {
      crop: {
        width: 1600,
        height: 900,
        originX:
          uploadResult.width > uploadResult.height
            ? (uploadResult.height - uploadResult.width) / 2
            : (uploadResult.width - uploadResult.height) / 2,
        originY: 0,
      },
    },
  ],
  { compress: 0.7, format: SaveFormat.JPEG }
);
```

Unfortunately, this resizes/crops the `1800x1200` image to `1350x900`, not `1600x900`.

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I'm using the Expo's `manipulateAsync` (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/), but it's more of a javascript/mathematical question than a library issue. Basically I'm not sure how to calculate the 1. reisze and 2. crop of the image so the result can be 16:9.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to calculate and cap the size of the image using its aspect ratio.

```
const ratio = uploadResult.width / uploadResult.height;

let newWidth = ratio * 900;
let newHeight = 900;

if (ratio > 0) {
    newWidth = 1600;
    newHeight = 1600 / ratio;
}

const resizeResult = await manipulateAsync(
  uploadResult.uri,
  [
    {
      resize: { height: newHeight, width: newWidth }
    }
  ],
  { compress: 0.7, format: SaveFormat.JPEG }
);
```